# How to show the name of which slice is clicked in high chart-piechart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart(high chart) to show the work done by various employees in a department. Everything is working fine. Now I have a requirement to show the name of which slice is clicked when the drill down chart is clicked,so that after downloading the PDF report i can know the source of the drill down.Sample code is as below:

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Employee Activities'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the slices to view drilldown.'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Work Load',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Mr.A',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Mr.A'
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.B',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Mr.B'
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.C',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Mr.C'
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.D',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Ms.D'
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.F',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Ms.F'
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.Z',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Mr.A',
                id: 'Mr.A',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 24.13],
                    ['W2', 17.2],
                    ['W3', 8.11],
                    ['W4', 5.33],
                    ['W5', 1.06],
                    ['W6', 0.5]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.B',
                id: 'Mr.B',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 5],
                    ['W2', 4.32],
                    ['W3', 3.68],
                    ['W4', 2.96],
                    ['W5', 2.53],
                    ['W6', 1.45]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.C',
                id: 'Mr.C',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 2.76],
                    ['W2', 2.32],
                    ['W3', 2.31],
                    ['W4', 1.27]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.D',
                id: 'Ms.D',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 2.56],
                    ['W2', 0.77],
                    ['W3', 0.42],
                    ['W4', 0.3],
                    ['W5', 0.29],
                    ['W6', 0.26],
                    ['W7', 0.17]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.F',
                id: 'Ms.F',
                data: [
                    ['W7', 0.34],
                    ['W9', 0.24],
                    ['W10', 0.17],
                    ['W11', 0.16]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

Now If I download the drill down chart, the PDF does not show the name of which slice is downloaded.

Please help me with displaying the name of which drill down is downloaded in the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the title in chart-> events -> drilldown/drillup events.

```
events: {
    drilldown: function(e) {

        this.setTitle({
            text: e.seriesOptions.name
        });
    },
    drillup: function(e) {
        this.setTitle({
            text: 'Employee Activities'
        });
    }
}
```

The working fiddle for same can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bnrfk3sv/)

So your final chart node would be something like below.

```
chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
            this.setTitle({
                text: e.seriesOptions.name
            });
        },
        drillup: function(e) {
            this.setTitle({
                text: 'Employee Activities'
            });
        }
    },


}
```

Comment: Thanks @J-D ..I was looking for the same

Comment: Sorry to ask for more, but what should i do if i want to show from date and to date in the chart title. I have two date pickers in my page.This chart displays the  work  done by employees between date ranges.

Comment: The text:"" is just a string. You can concat what ever you want to that string and it will reflect in your chart title. So text: e.seriesOptions.name + '-' + startDate + '-' + endDate

Comment: how can i access the selected dates and concatenate. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try add code  below code

```
 exporting: {
        filename: 'custom-file-name'
    }
```

now you set file name according your requirement .

Comment: While Exporting the file, i need to save as "which portion was clicked".pdf

Comment: Example: Mr A.pdf if A's drilldown is exported or Mr B.pdf if B's drilldown was exported

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have problems with finding name of the clicked drilldown.
Here's how you can do it [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2g6drkm/2/) (code below). Then you can use that name in download.

This is how your *plotOptions* should look like:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                },
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            //Clicked drilldown name will be alerted here
                            //You can use it in naming PDF
                            alert(this.name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

...here's full code:

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Employee Activities'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the slices to view drilldown.'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                },
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            //Clicked drilldown name will be alerted here
                            //You can use it in naming PDF
                            alert(this.name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Work Load',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Mr.A',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Mr.A'
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.B',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Mr.B'
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.C',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Mr.C'
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.D',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Ms.D'
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.F',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Ms.F'
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.Z',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Mr.A',
                id: 'Mr.A',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 24.13],
                    ['W2', 17.2],
                    ['W3', 8.11],
                    ['W4', 5.33],
                    ['W5', 1.06],
                    ['W6', 0.5]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.B',
                id: 'Mr.B',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 5],
                    ['W2', 4.32],
                    ['W3', 3.68],
                    ['W4', 2.96],
                    ['W5', 2.53],
                    ['W6', 1.45]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Mr.C',
                id: 'Mr.C',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 2.76],
                    ['W2', 2.32],
                    ['W3', 2.31],
                    ['W4', 1.27]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.D',
                id: 'Ms.D',
                data: [
                    ['W1', 2.56],
                    ['W2', 0.77],
                    ['W3', 0.42],
                    ['W4', 0.3],
                    ['W5', 0.29],
                    ['W6', 0.26],
                    ['W7', 0.17]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Ms.F',
                id: 'Ms.F',
                data: [
                    ['W7', 0.34],
                    ['W9', 0.24],
                    ['W10', 0.17],
                    ['W11', 0.16]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```